# Every DependsOn value must be a string - How to explode a Mapping for the DependsOn property

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am using the [explode transform](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Explode) macro in the following manner.

```
  ServiceMap:
    Private:
      Prefix: Private
    Public:
      Prefix: Public

  Service:
    ExplodeMap: ServiceMap
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      - !Sub 'LoadBalancerRule${!Explode Prefix}'
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref "ECSCluster"
      ...
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition!Explode Prefix
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Sub '!Explode Prefix${ServiceName}'
          ContainerPort: !Ref "ContainerPort"
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup!Explode Prefix

  LoadBalancerRule:
    ExplodeMap: ServiceMap
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
      ...
      ListenerArn: !Ref "LoadBalancerListener"
      Priority: !Ref "Priority"
```

This seems to be successful, but for transformation specified within the `DependsOn` property. As I create the stack, this is the error I receive:

```
Template format error: Every DependsOn value must be a string.
```

Questions:
- I don't know how to actually view the transformed template
- Why does this happen? As per the doc, [!Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) creates a string

Any ideas how t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what the difference between `!Sub 'LoadBalancerRule${!Explode Prefix}'` &  `- LoadBalancerRule!Explode Prefix` is, but this worked out

```
  Service:
    ExplodeMap: ServiceMap
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      - LoadBalancerRule!Explode Prefix
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref "ECSCluster"
      ...
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition!Explode Prefix
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Sub '!Explode Prefix${ServiceName}'
          ContainerPort: !Ref "ContainerPort"
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup!Explode Prefix
```